# How to find the orthogonal vector in Lagrange Method of solving PDE (Quasilinear equations)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> **Example 2.7** Solve the equation $u_x + 3y^{2/3}u_y = 2$ subject to the initial condition $u(x,1) = 1+x$.

It's an example in "An introduction to partial differential equations" book by Yehuda Pinchover, to be solved by the method of characteristics. And I'm trying to solve it by Lagrange's method. I know that I need to find 2 orthogonal vectors so I can find $Ψ$ and $Φ$. But my struggles is finding the 2 orthogonal vectors.

Comment: Whos is the author of the book ?

Comment: [link](http://msvlab.hre.ntou.edu.tw/grades/PDE/%E8%A9%B3%E8%A7%A3/solutionManual-pde-pinchover.pdf) 
page 39 I couldn't see the similarity in the book.. @EditPiAf

Comment: The author is Yehuda Pinchover @Aryadeva

Comment: Thank you Lama @LAMAS.M

Answer (score 0):

$$u_x + 3y^{2/3}u_y = 2$$
The Charpit-Lagrange equations are :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{ 3y^{2/3}}=\frac{du}{2}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{ 3y^{2/3}}$ :
$$x-y^{1/3}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{2}$ :
$$u-2x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is : $\quad c_2=F(c_1)=u-2x=F(x-y^{1/3})$ :
$$\boxed{u=2x+F(x-y^{1/3})}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function in the general case.

In the particular case with condition $u(x,1)=1+x$ the function F is non longer arbitrary.
$$1+x=2x+F(x-1^{1/3})=2x+F(x-1)$$
Let $X=x-1\quad\implies\quad x=X+1$
$$1+(X+1)=2(X+1)+F(X)$$
$$F(X)=-X$$
Now the function $F(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution where $X=x-y^{1/3}$ :
$$u=2x-(x-y^{1/3})$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=x+y^{1/3}}$$